# Process different part of large file using different tool without large IO

Tags: python, c++, ios

The input of my program is a large file of human genetic variants(~50G). It can be divided into 24 parts(as human has 24 chromosomes), different part of the file need to be processed by a tool with different parameters(consider them as different tools). The large file has many lines, each line start with an ID, and ID indicate which tool should process it. Lines are sorted by ID in the large file.

Note each line can not be processed independently, lines with same ID are not independent. Line with different ID are independent.

Each tool can parallel process its own input.

It is a text file, a sample of the file:

> #1       10109   .       A       T
>
> #1       10146   .       ACC     AC
>
> ...
>
> #24       10291   .       C       T

Previously I write a python script, divide large file into 24 small files, and then call different tool to process each of them.

The problem is that now IO is the bottleneck. Because I have to read file, and write into small file, each small file need to be read for processing again.

Comment: Show a sample (small part of it) of a file, I guess it is a text file, isn't it?

Comment: If each line in the file is fixed length, this means that you can calculate the position of line #n in the file. In which case, you can simply mmap() the contents of the file, and spawn off a number of threads to chew through each corresponding section of the file. If lines are of variable length, and thus the location of each chunk of data cannot be independently computed, you have no options. You cannot avoid having to read the entire file. It's fundamental.

Comment: what kind of tools do you apply on your file's parts? can you use AWK?

Comment: can you process data using your tools in parallel during reading your data?

Comment: the length of line is different, can I avoid write them into small files and read them again because the lines are sorted by id?

Comment: Do the individual tools process the data sequentially? Do you have any ability to modify the code for those tools?

Comment: if your data is sorted by ID, you can simply read the file into memory until the ID will be changed and process read data by the corresponding tool. So you don't need to read data again. Just sort your tools correspondingly and call them for each data chunk

Comment: Each tool can parallel process its own input.

Comment: can all of your tools be implemented in Python?

Comment: large file is read by my program, how can those small tools read data chuck directly from my program?

Comment: I can't answer your question not knowing what kind of tools are you using - is it a set of binary programs expecting files as an input? can those tools work with STDIN? are those tools written by you, i.e. do you have control over it? etc./etc./...

Comment: suggest research - 'work queue', inter-thread communications, inter-process communications.

Comment: When I handle bigger files (that can not sit in my system ram), I use my ssd.  At the moment, my main drive is atypical, it has an ssd cache front end.  HW bottle neck, maybe needs HW upgrades.

Comment: Point of order, sir, but humans have 23 (or 46) chromosomes.